# Enclosing section in minipage creates an extra new page

Tags: formatting, minipage, titlesec

Im creating a document with `multi={minipage}` so i can manage the page length with minipages, i want to enclose section in one as well and i did using the following code, problem is, whenever `\section{}` command its used a blank page is created before, how to remove it?

```
\documentclass[
    class=article,
    multi={minipage},
    border={3mm},
]{standalone}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]
{
    \noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
    \normalfont\Large\bfseries%
}
{\thesection}
{1em}{}%
[\end{minipage}]

\begin{document}
\section{test}
\end{document}
```